# How to get or set the type for property in Vue template slot scope?

Tags: typescript, vuejs3

Using scoped slots, how to automatically get the types inferred from the props?

Or at least assert it manually, e.g using `as`.

```js
<!-- AppTable.vue -->

<script setup lang="ts">
import { ref } from 'vue';

defineProps<{ items: unknown[] }>();
</script>

<template>
  <table>
    <thead>
      <slot name="thead"></slot>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr v-for="(item, index) in items" :key="item.id">
        <slot name="tbody" :item="item" :index="index"></slot>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</template>
```

```js
<!-- App.vue -->

<script setup lang="ts">
import AppTable from './AppTable.vue';

interface Customer {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  email: string;
}

const customers: Customer[] = [
  { id: 1, name: 'John', email: 'john@example.com' },
  { id: 2, name: 'Jim', email: 'jim@example.com' },
  { id: 3, name: 'Jack', email: 'jack@example.com' },
];
</script>

<template>
  <div style="margin-bottom: 2rem">
    <app-table :items="customers">
      <template #thead>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Email</th>
      </template>
      <template #tbody="{ item: customer, index }">
        <td>{{ index+1 }}</td>
        <td>{{ customer.name }}</td><!-- error TS18046: 'customer' is of type 'unknown'. -->
        <td>{{ customer.email }}</td><!-- error TS18046: 'customer' is of type 'unknown'. -->
      </template>
    </app-table>
  </div>
</template>
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-kqmmnc?file=src%2FApp.vue)

Open new terminal there and run `npm run type-check`

I have tried this:

```js
<!-- App.vue -->
<template #tbody="{ item: customer, index }: {item: Customer, index: number}"></template>
<!-- 
error TS2322: Type '{ item: unknown; index: number; }' is not assignable to type '{ item: Customer; index: number; }'.
  Types of property 'item' are incompatible.
    Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'Customer'.
-->
```

This works, but I'm avoiding `any` if possible.

```
// AppTable.vue
defineProps<{ items: any }>();
// Unexpected any. Specify a different type. (eslint@typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any)
```

```js
<!-- App.vue -->
<template #tbody="{ item: customer, index }: {item: Customer, index: number}"></template>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use vue's generic script tag for this.
See more here: https://vuejs.org/api/sfc-script-setup.html#generics

```
<!-- AppTable.vue -->
<script setup lang="ts" generic="T extends { id: number }">

defineProps<{
    items: Array<T>
}>();

</script>
```